# Why can't VS create a VSPackage project with a Custom Editor?

Tags: projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2010, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to create a VSPackage project (using the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK), which works perfectly when I don't add a Custom Editor. But when I do, it's stuck at "Creating project VSPackageX..." and Visual Studio is basically unresponsive.

There's nothing in the Event Log and I don't know where the log files for Visual Studio are located.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I switched off ReSharper (Tools -> Options -> ReSharper -> Suspend), and this solved the same problem for me.